# How to calculate the algorithmic complexity of Python functions?

Tags: python, complexity-theory, big-o

When required to show how efficient the algorithm is, we need to show the algorithmic complexity of functions - [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and so on. In Python code, how can we show or calculate the bounds of functions?

Answer (score 7):

In general, there's no way to do this programmatically (you run into the halting problem).

If you have no idea where to start, you can gain some insight into how a function will perform by running some benchmarks (e.g. using the `time` module) with inputs of various sizes. You can even collect enough data to form a *suspicion* about what the runtime might be. But this won't give you a rigorous answer - for that, you need to *prove* mathematically that your suspected bound is in fact true.

For instance, if I'm playing with a sorting function and observe that the time is increasing roughly proportionally to the square of the input size, I might *suspect* that the complexity of this sort is `O(n**2)`. But this does not constitute proof - in particular, some algorithms that perform well under typical inputs have pathological inputs that result in very poor performance.

To prove that the bound is in fact `O(n**2)`, I need to look at what the algorithm is doing in the worst case - in this example, I might be analysing a selection sort, which repeatedly sweeps across the entire unsorted portion of the list and picks the lowest unsorted number. It should be evident that I'm examining something like `n*(n-1) == O(n**2)` elements. If examining elements is a constant-time operation, and placing the final element in the correct place is also not worse than `O(n**2)`, then it follows that my entire algorithm is `O(n**2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the big O notation for your own functions, you probably need variables keeping track of things like:
the runTime; the number of comparisons; the number of iterations; etc. As well as some calculation investigating how these correspond to the size of your data.
It's probably best to do this manually first, so you can check your understanding of an algorithm.